# Modal box is not opening

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a CSS/HTML modal and I believe that no JavaScript is necessary. Here is the sample code that I am using. The modal won't open, but it shows that its linking to it. I have 3 CSS files and I added it to the bootstrap.css and the stylishportfolio.css but not the bootstrap.min.css.

```html
 <a href="#openModal">
 <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/Johannesburg2.jpg">
 <p style="position: absolute; top: 9em; right: 12em; class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><a   href="#about"  class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Johannesburg</a>
</p>
                                </a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

Comment: if U use Bootstrap then please check this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Check CSS is coming from `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.min.css`. After doing that, put your code into the file where CSS is coming from.

Comment: I wanted to edit your question but I didn't even know where to start. Please rephrase your question and remove any unnecessary content.

Comment: @demo U is the chemical symbol for Uranium. "If Uranium use Bootstrap" isn't grammatically correct; it should be "If Uranium use**s** Bootstrap".

Comment: You should read more documentation.

Comment: Your code is all messed up...

Comment: Sorry guys very new to this, thats why im asking. Im not sure what isnt unnecessay content there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap simply instantiate the modals through data attributes.

like below.

Steps

---

1. Please make sure that bootstrap core css and js are loaded

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

### 2. Write Modal Instantiating button like this.

```
 <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
```

---

### 3. Write your HTML Modal like this

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <!-- MODAL CONTENT -->
</div>
```

---

For More Details See this link :

Comment: When you say " Please make sure that bootstrap core css and js are loaded"?

Comment: For a bootstrap UI framework it has mainly a css file like bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.css (not minified version) and a custom override style version or theme style for eg. style.css. And in JS part after the JQUERY Library is loaded bootstrap js library should be loaded (bootstrap.min.js)  This is the common way to use bootstrap functionalities. If the JS is loaded the items like bootstrap modal, toggles and accordions will not work. If these things are perfect then also check whether any jquery error exists in your page.